# How to set default PS layer to be transparent

Tags: adobe-photoshop, layers

My work has been using CS3 for far to long so I finally got them to upgrade to the CC suite.

This has been great but I only have one problem. I can't remember how to change the default PS layer to be transparent! I made this change to my mac at home about 2 years ago and just can't remember where the setting is stored at.

This is how the default layer looks,

[image: Solid color layer]

This is how I want the default layer to be,

[image: Transparent layer]

Anyone know how to change this setting? Every time I Google it I get how to apply opacity which is far from what I was looking for.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you create a new document, change the "Background Contents" from White to *Transparent*.

[image: New Document Dialog]

Answer (score 2):

you can also just use the presets... and save your background per preset.

Answer (score 0):

Just go to **File > New** put Size 600×600, Resolution 72, and background Contents to Transparency.